# MVC IRouteConstraint Entity Framework performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to make my MVC application as efficient as possible. I have just come across the following problem which I am not sure could be solved in Entity Framework or MVC.

I have the following route:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                "UserNameRoute",
                "{UserName}/{Action}",
                new { controller = "UserName", action = "Index" },
                new
                {
                    UserName = new UserConstraint(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepository>())
                });
```

Then the following route constraint:

```
    private readonly IUserRepository repository;

    public UserConstraint(IUserRepository repository)
    {
        if (repository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
        }

        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (!values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var siteRoot = (string)values[parameterName];

        var user = this.repository.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && !u.Archived);

        if (user!= null)
        {
            values[parameterName] = user;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then all my controller needs for each action is:

```
    public ActionResult ExampleAction(User userName)
    {
        return this.View(userName);
    }
```

This works great I can receive my user in to the action no problem at all. The problem come that when I put an action link in the view like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View some action or other", "someaction", new { UserName = Model.UserName }, new { @class = "myclass" })
```

This action link above will route through my IRouteConstraint as it should and do another database select on the DB to get the same user it had before. It will do this for each action link on the page. Is there a more efficient way of doing this so the database select is only performed once?

I should probably point out I am using a code first with EF. I'm not using a generic repository or my own rolled unit of work. I am using version 4 of MVC and v4.3 of Entity Framework.

Comment: have you thought about using a custom model binder instead of a route constraint?  that way the query hit would only happen when coming in, not when creating the link

Comment: I think you may be on to something. Let me get my head around it and I'll post my solution once I have it.

Comment: You could also cache the User object in HttpContext.Current.Items, then just return it if it already has been loaded.

Comment: Ah yes. That works. Good suggestion. I really like the solution but somehow it doesn't seem like the conventional way of doing it if you know what I mean? I'll take a bit more of a look at a custom model binder and see if that solves it too. Your suggestion is a good quick fix. Cheers!